# x86 NASM | Input in Loop working only the first and third time

Tags: linux, assembly, input, x86, nasm

I have a loop that runs succesfully 3 times, but the input I have in this loop works only the first time.
I am new to assembly so pls have patience.

**Code:**

```
section .bss
|    d times 3 resb 1 ;array to store input
|    i resb 1         ;counter

section .text
|    global _start
|
|    _start:
|    |    mov ecx, 3
|    |    mov [i], byte 0
|    |
|    |    loop_here:
|    |    |    push ecx
|    |    |
|    |    |    mov eax, 3
|    |    |    mov ebx, 0
|    |    |    mov ecx, d
|    |    |    add ecx, [i]
|    |    |    inc byte [i]
|    |    |    mov edx, 1
|    |    |    int 80h
|    |    |
|    |    |    pop ecx
|    |    loop loop_here
|    |
|    |    mov eax, 1
|    |    xor ebx, ebx
|    |    int 80h
```

**Output:**

```
2 ;I inserted 2 as an input
2 ;I inserted 2 again as input
[Program finishes]
```

Well, later I thought that the loop might not running a third time, so I changed the code a bit.

**New Code:**

```
section .bss
|    d times 3 resb 1 ;array to store input
|    i resb 1         ;counter

section .text
|    global _start
|
|    _start:
|    |    mov ecx, 3
|    |    mov [i], byte 0
|    |
|    |    loop_here:
|    |    |    push ecx
|    |    |
|    |    |    mov eax, 4
|    |    |    mov ebx, 1
|    |    |    mov ecx, i
|    |    |    add [ecx], byte 30h ;to actually print the count
|    |    |    mov edx, 1
|    |    |    int 80h
|    |    |    sub [i], byte 30h ;to make again a counter
|    |    |    
|    |    |    mov eax, 3
|    |    |    mov ebx, 0
|    |    |    mov ecx, d
|    |    |    add ecx, [i]
|    |    |    inc byte [i]
|    |    |    mov edx, 1
|    |    |    int 80h
|    |    |
|    |    |    pop ecx
|    |    loop loop_here
|    |
|    |    mov eax, 1
|    |    xor ebx, ebx
|    |    int 80h
```

**New Output:**

```
02
122
[Program finishes]
```

**Explaination:**

0 is the counter and 2 my input. 1 and 2 are the counter and the second 2 is my second input, which means that the loop runs succesfully, it just ignores the code for input the second time it runs

**Also**, do the straight lines I have in my code to visualize the scopes make my code any more readable?

Comment: Your code doesn't even assemble, make sure you post what you are actually running. As for your problem, you are also reading the newline but that should still allow you to read two digits (digit newline digit) unless you supplied some extra input too. PS: `add ecx, [i]` uses wrong size.

Comment: @Jester You were right, I changed my question a bit, both code and output

Comment: It would be easier to keep `i` in a register, and also use a register other than ECX for your loop counter.  You haven't used EDI or ESI.  Only use memory when you run out of registers.  A byte variable in memory is just inconvenient for no benefit.

Comment: @Peter Cordes I understand why you telling me these but what I dont understand is why I should use other register instead of `ecx` for my loop

Comment: @Peter Cordes Also, do you recommend using `edi` or `esi` instead of `i`, or I dont get something?

Comment: You're already using ECX *inside* the loop as a pointer, so it would be easier and simpler to loop with `dec esi` / `jnz` instead of push/pop ecx + a `loop` instruction.  You do need a buffer in memory to `write` from, though, so you couldn't just keep `i` in a register, nevermind that suggestion, I didn't read your code carefully enough to see what it was doing with `i`.

Comment: Did you hit return in between your two 2's?  That's a character of input also, and that may be what your second call to `read` is reading.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge what do you mean by "hit return"?

Comment: Literally, pressing the Return or Enter key on your keyboard, assuming your program is reading from a terminal.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge to be honest(and pls don't judge me) I don't know what the return key on the keyboard is, but I am pressing "enter"

Comment: Just two names for the same thing.  Okay, so you're pressing Enter.  That means the data you read is going to be three characters: `2`, `\n`, `2`.  The second time through the loop, you are reading `\n`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Peter already did a great job of covering most of this in the comments, but I thought I'd go into more detail:

The x86 `loop` instruction assumes you have a counter in `ecx`. `loop` automatically decrements `ecx` and jumps to the loop label if `ecx` is **not** 0. Since you're calling linux syscalls in a loop, and linux expects the buffer pointer to be in `ecx`, you should probably use a different register as your loop counter and some sort of jump instruction to do this instead:

```
mov esi, 3    ; esi is your loop counter - loop 3 times
loop_here:

; do syscall

dec esi       ; decrement loop counter
jnz loop_here ; jump to loop_here if esi is not zero
```

However, calling syscalls in a loop is not very efficient. Instead, you could do something like this:

```
mov eax, 3    ; read
mov ebx, 0    ; fd for stdin
mov ecx, d    ; address of d buffer into ecx
mov edx, 3    ; read 3 characters at most, the size of your buffer
int 80h

mov esi, eax  ; read returns the number of bytes read in eax. 
              ; we'll save it in esi
xor edi, edi  ; edi will be our loop counter, this makes it 0

loop_here:    ; first, we'll print the loop counter value
mov eax, 4    ; write
mov ebx, 1    ; fd for stdout
mov ecx, i    ; address of i for write
mov edx, 1    ; write 1 byte

add edi, '0'  ; convert edi loop counter to ASCII
mov [i], byte edi ; put lower byte of edi in i

int 80h

sub edi, '0'  ; restore edi

mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1
mov ecx, d    ; address of d for write, 
add ecx, edi  ; plus current loop counter (offset)
mov edx, 1
int 80h

inc edi       ; increment loop counter
cmp esi, edi  ; compare to number of bytes read
jne loop_here ; jump to loop_here if not equal
```

This calls *read* once, but still calls *write* in a loop to write the counter and values of `d`.

To skip the trailing newline in your input, you could try doing this after your call to *read* (remember `eax` has the number of bytes read):

```
movzx edi, byte [d+eax-1] ; move and zero-extend last byte of d into edi
cmp edi, `\n`             ; is it a newline? (backticks required)
jne skip                  ; skip if not
dec eax                   ; otherwise, we'll print one less byte
skip:
; rest of your code here
```

The newline will still be stored in memory, but you won't print it, because you'll loop one fewer times.

Comment: ok, I get that, but I am `push`ing and `pop`ing `ecx` to the stack, before and after system calls respectively

Comment: Since your terminal is buffered, input is not sent to it until you press enter, meaning read also stores the newline from enter - which is what it prints after 2 (nothing). Also, you should avoid using memory if you have registers available.

Comment: Try running your program like this: `echo -n "abc" | ./a.out`

Comment: and how do I delete the stored new line? since, by what I understand from what you are saying, the new line is stored to the next item, to "delete" the stored new line, I have to reset the next item to zero? if set each element of d to be 2 bytes, will that be solved?

Comment: Your understanding is correct. There's a lot of ways you could skip printing/looping for the LF, but you can't skip storing it. read will read the specified number of bytes from the fd regardless of what their content is. I've added an example that you could use to my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I had an issue with formatting - my comment now contains the example code. Like I said, there's a lot of other ways you could accomplish that - including overwriting the newline with some other character if you wish. Or running your program with the echo command above to not give it a newline in the read. Or giving it more than 3 bytes of input, which would mean the newline is never read because it only reads the first 3 bytes.